# How to extract data from select option on web page to excel python

Tags: python-2.7

I am really new in python and i would like to extract data from select option to my computer, better to be orgenaized in excel.
can anyone help?

Comment: i am really new so just what i saw on internet like:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib.request

webpage = "http://www.fuel-economy.co.uk/mpg.php"

websource = urllib.request.urlopen(webpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(websource.read(), "html.parser")

span = soup.find("span", {"id": "winning_num_0"})
print (span)

Output is here...
<span id="winning_num_0"></span>

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and 
"[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". And more importantly, please read 
[the Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). 
You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).